# How to register a form with register Controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, registration

I am new to Laravel. I want to register new users using registerController. But when I try to register, it is showing error as unable to handle request.

My registration form in blade.php as:

```
<?php  $res= DB::table('states')->orderBy('name','asc')->get(); 

 ?>
    <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post" class="form-register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <select name="role" class="form-control"  required>
                                           
                        <?php  $roles= DB::table('roles')->where('id','>',1)->get(); ?>
                        @foreach($roles as $r)
                        <option value="{{$r->id}}">{{$r->description}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                        
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{-- First Name field --}}
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                    value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.full_name') }}" autofocus>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *" name="last_name" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email *" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control phoneMask" placeholder="Phone *" name="phone" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control phoneMask" placeholder="Cell" name="cell" value="">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Business Name *" name="business_name" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tax ID *" name="tax_id" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address *" name="address" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City *" name="city" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    
                    <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Select a State *</option>
                    
                        @foreach($res as $r)                          
                       
                        <option value="{{$r->code}}">{{$r->name}}</option>
                         @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control zipMask" placeholder="Zip *" name="zip" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" value="USA" readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mailing Address *" name="mailing_address" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mailing City *" name="mailing_city" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <select name="mailing_state" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">Select a Mailing State *</option>
                          @foreach($res as $r)                          
                       
                        <option value="{{$r->code}}">{{$r->name}}</option>
                         @endforeach
                        
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control zipMask" placeholder="Mailing Zip *" name="mailing_zip" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">                                
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="sameMailing" value="Yes"> Is chemical delivery address same as mailing address?
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Chemical Delivery Address *" name="chemical_delivery_address" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Chemical Delivery City *" name="chemical_delivery_city" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <select name="chemical_delivery_state" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select a Chemical Delivery State *</option>
                         @foreach($res as $r)                          
                       
                        <option value="{{$r->code}}">{{$r->name}}</option>
                         @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control zipMask" placeholder="Chemical Delivery Zip *" name="chemical_delivery_zip" value="" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <label>Fork Lift&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="fork_lift" value="Yes"> Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="fork_lift" value="No"> No
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <label>Dock&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="dock" value="Yes"> Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="dock" value="No"> No
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{-- Password field --}}
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror"
                        placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.password') }}">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_icon', '') }}"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                {{-- Confirm password field --}}
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation"
                        class="form-control @error('password_confirmation') is-invalid @enderror"
                        placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.retype_password') }}">

                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <span class="fas fa-lock {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_icon', '') }}"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @error('password_confirmation')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Restricted Use Pesticide Number *" name="pesticide_num" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control date" placeholder="Date *" name="pesticide_date" value="" required>
                    
                </div>
            </div>     

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <label>RUP License&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="file" name="rup_license" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg,.gif,.pdf"> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <label>Would you be interested in shared storage for your ag chemicals through one of Farmerce's Buyer PODS?&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="additional_storage" value="Yes"> Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="radio" name="additional_storage" value="No"> No
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-4">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <div class="field-group recaptcha">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-offset-4 submit_btn">

            {{-- Register button --}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_btn', 'btn-flat btn-primary') }}">
            <span class="fas fa-user-plus"></span>
            {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.register') }}
        </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Register Controller as:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller{
   

    use RegistersUsers;

 
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        /*return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);*/
         $user= User::create([
            'name'              => $data['name'],            
            'last_name'         => $data['last_name'],
            'email'             => $data['email'],
            'password'          => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'mobile'             => $data['cell']
            
        ]);

       
       return $user; 
}}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I am trying to save only users' data. But it is not updating to the database. When I clicked the register button, it is showing unable to handle request. How to fix this error. I want to save this form data to database. I am not familiar in laravel, I am trying to register form using laravel registerController. how to save this form in database using registerController.

Comment: Is the controller method is called? if you dd  something inthe create function in the validation does it appear? One mistake for sure: fi you want to upload files, change the form enctype to enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @Mátyás Grőger Controller method is not called.

Comment: @MátyásGrőger Updated enctype, again error occurs

Comment: what is $register_url is it the same which brings you to the register controller?

Comment: @Mátyás Grőger Updated my code. But Not working , it is again showing HTTP Error 500

Comment: Edit your `.env` file and set `APP_DEBUG=true`,  and send proper error message, because we need more details, and error 500 is too general to even discuss ;-)